# Is there a way to automatically adjust the VARCHAR limit based on the max length of the string in the column?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is there a way to automatically adjust the `VARCHAR` limit based on the max length of the string in the column or do I have to manually find out and set the max length?

Comment: Why do you think you need re-adjust the length? Set it to an appropriate value that accomodates the expected range of values.

Comment: As I'm inserting values into the column it could vary (meaning be much larger than a limit I had set based on previous string lengths). I was wondering if there was a way. But that's fine if there isn't. I'll just estimate it then.

Comment: just use `varchar(max)`

Comment: Don't "just use varchar(max)" unless you have a reasonable expectation that > 8,000 bytes will be needed. e.g. using for a person's name would be ridiculous. Oversized string columns affect memory grants and max has additional performance overhead (in addition to preventing you indexing it). no there is no way to automatically adjust the VARCHAR limit - you need to look at any specifications from upstream that may restrict the length of data or just guesstimate it with sufficient wriggle room for uncertainty.

Comment: A *good* application layer will limit the number of characters the user can enter to match that of the size of the field. If you have a column that's defined as a `varchar(50)`, allowing a user to enter to enter as many characters as they want in the application is a flaw.

Comment: Thanks all for all of the useful information. I'll bare this in mind when creating columns. varchar(max) does sound scary indeed. @MartinSmith please post your answer in the answer section so I could mark it as an answer. Everyone thank you for supporting.